# Average of entered numbers in C - sum always 0

Tags: c

Here is a code which evaluates the average of 10 entered numbers. Problem is it doesn't seem to print the sum correctly (it's always equal to 0) after exiting the loop, everything else is working fine.

```
int count=0, n=10, c;
float sum=0, x;
do{
    printf("x=");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    count++;
    sum+=x;
}
while(count<n);
printf("Sum is %d", sum);
printf("\nCount is: %d", count);
printf("\nThe Average of the numbers is : %0.2f", sum/count);
getch();
}
```

Another question is how to exit the loop after a symbol is reached(i.e. without setting a limit to the number of integers to be entered).

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If it didn't warn you about the type mismatch between `%d` and `sum`, then you need to turn on warnings so that it does.  If it doesn't have options to turn on such warnings, get a better compiler!  Were I to compile your code with my default warnings, the compiler would let me know in no uncertain terms that the code was incorrect.

Comment: I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010. Especially for this code it comes up with 0 warnings, no messages or errors. Perhaps it's the settings in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%f` format specifier for floating point numbers.

```
printf("Sum is %f", sum);
```

To exit the loop on a symbol, you could check the return value from `scanf`. `scanf` returns the number of items read. If it returns 0 then the user didn't type a valid number.

```
while (1) {
    printf("x=");

    if (scanf("%f", &x) != 1) {
        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

`break` exits the current loop.

Comment: Given that the average uses `%0.2f` already, I wonder if that part boils down to a typo on the OP's part.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question it should be printf("%f",sum) to print the correct sum. Since you are using float you have to use %f, if you use int it is %d. For your second question, you can do something like this (modify it accordingly):

```
int main(){ 
// Declare Variables 
int count = 0; float sum = 0, currentNum = 0;

// Ask user for input 
while(currentNum > -1)
{ 
   printf("Enter integer to be averaged (enter -1 to get avg):"); 
   scanf("%f",&currentNum); 
   if(currentNum == -1)
       break; 

   // Check the entered number and computed sum
   printf("You entered: %0.2f\n", currentNum); 
   sum += currentNum; 
   printf("Current sum: %0.2f\n", sum);
   count++; 
}

// Print Average
printf("Average is: %0.2f\n", sum/count); 

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Entering a sentinel value is OK, but the code should also test that `scanf()` succeeded.  Suppose the user fumble-fingers and types `1q`. The first `scanf()` will set `currentNum` to `1.0`, but the next will not alter it and will return 0 (not EOF, not 1) to indicate that there was a problem.  You *must* check the return status from `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you could do this:

```
scanf("%f", &x);
if (x==0) {
  break;
}
```

This will break you out of the loop if you enter 0, then your loop can be infinite:

```
do {

} while(true)
```

Comment: That is not correct. `scanf()` assigns nothing to `x` when it gets a conversion failure or EOF.

Comment: I didn't know that, indeed, use the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, I think EOF may be the better solution:

`while(scanf("%f", &x) != EOF)`

Comment: Testing `scanf()` is good; testing it correctly is better. If it returns zero (as it might, for example, if it encounters an 'N', say, in the input stream), your code will continue as if all was OK. You need to check for the expected number of items: `while (scanf("%f", &x) == 1)`.